# Remove property/class member decorators with mapped types

Tags: typescript, typegoose

I'm using typegoose to define my mongoose/mongo-db models. A typegoose model could look like

```
class Something {
  @prop({ required: true }) // this is now required in the schema
  public firstName!: string;

  @prop() // by default, a property is not required
  public lastName?: string; // using the "?" marks the property as optional
}
```

(from https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/docs/decorators/prop/)

I would like to reuse the classes to get various typescript interfaces for e.g. api calls.

How would I do to strip all `@prop(...)`-lines and generate something that looks like

```
interface Something {
  firstName: string,
  lastName?: string
}
```

I suppose I would like to use https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types but I'm not sure of that.

Comment: That decorator shouldn't affect TS compile-time types. For example you can create an interface from `Something` by `interface SomethingI extends Something { }` and then use it like `type T1 = keyof SomethingI // "firstName" | "lastName"`

Answer (score 0):

as @ford04 already stated, typegoose's decorators dont change the class when you want to use it with `new` or as an type